# I am trying to plot confidence intervals on a regression graph.

Tags: r, regression, lm, confidence-interval

I have tried a few methods, but all of them gives me an error saying that the x and y values are not the same.

This is what i have done so far.

```
head(new_data[,4:5])

 Humerus   Radius
 4.992607 4.921148
 5.170484 5.049856
 5.005623 4.936989
 5.065755 4.976734
 4.219508 4.174387
 4.262680 4.157319

plot(new_data$Radius, new_data$Humerus, main="Regression analysis of Humerus to radius", 
 xlab="Radius ", ylab=" Humerus", pch=19)
abline(lm(new_data$Humerus~ new_data$Radius))
```

[This is the graph I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhPqA.png)

And to do the confidence intervals, I tried this

```
lm.out <- lm(new_data$Humerus ~ new_data$Radius)
newx = seq(min(new_data$Radius),max(new_data$Humerus),by = 0.05)
conf_interval <- predict(lm.out, newdata=data.frame(x=newx), interval="confidence",level = 0.95)
plot(new_data$Radius, new_data$Humerus, xlab="Radius", ylab="Humerus", main="Regression")
abline(lm.out, col="lightblue")
lines(newx, conf_interval[,2], col="blue", lty=2)
lines(newx, conf_interval[,3], col="blue", lty=2)
```

When I do this, error message keep popping up saying -

```
 Warning message:
'newdata' had 61 rows but variables found have 150 rows
```

I'm really stuck here, any kind of help would very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Could you run `length(newx)` and `nrow(conf_interval)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `predict()`, `newdata` should be a dataframe containing the same names as the explanatory variables in the original dataset.  In your original dataset, the x variable was called "new_data$Radius".  You need to make two changes:

1. When you do your original regression, just use the variable names

   lm.out <- lm(Humerus~Radius,data=new_data)
2. When you pass your `newdata` parameter, let the name be "Radius" not "x"

   conf_interval <- predict(lm.out, newdata=data.frame(Radius=newx), interval="confidence",level = 0.95)

So your code should read

```
lm.out <- lm(Humerus ~ $Radius,data=new_data)
newx = seq(min(new_data$Radius),max(new_data$Humerus),by = 0.05)
conf_interval <- predict(lm.out, newdata=data.frame(Radius=newx), interval="confidence",level = 0.95)
plot(new_data$Radius, new_data$Humerus, xlab="Radius", ylab="Humerus", main="Regression")
abline(lm.out, col="lightblue")
lines(newx, conf_interval[,2], col="blue", lty=2)
lines(newx, conf_interval[,3], col="blue", lty=2)
```

Comment: OMG!! it worked perfectly, thank you so much!! I really appreciate the help!